# Regex : Website url regular expression translation

Tags: regex, url, hyperlink

Here is regular expression for URLs:

```
(?<protocol>http|ftp)://(?<domain>[^/\r\n]+)(?<path>/[^\r\n]*)?
```

I'd like to know how can it be translated? As in what each character/flag means.

I know that:

`(?<protocol>http|ftp)://` :: 'protocol' is grouping name

`http|ftp` - http OR ftp

`://`  after protocol must be these characters

And then I'd like clarification on what the following means:

```
`(?<domain>[^/\r\n]+)(?<path>/[^\r\n]*)?`
```

Thank you

Comment: Go to [**Regex101**](http://regex101.com/#PCRE) and paste in `(?<domain>[^\/\r\n]+)(?<path>\/[^\r\n]*)?`

Comment: Great resource! Now it is clear for me. Thank you a lot!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is simply asking for an explanation of a regex

Answer (score 0):

When you specify `(?<text>(regex))` what you're doing is specifying a grouping name for a capture group. Capture groups can split how data is matched.

For example: (http|ftp)\: has only one capture group, but matches (http OR ftp) and the `:` character. Where the later is not specified in a capture group.

Capture groups are useful in many cases, like bash or Python, where you want a particular set of data. So if I wanted only http OR ftp, but I wanted to ensure it was followed by ':', I would specify that I want capture group 0.

Now back to the regex.

The regular expression alone would be (this will match `http://google.com`) with no grouping names:

```
(http|ftp)\:\/\/([^/\r\n]+)(\/[^\r\n]*)
```

`(http|ftp)` :: Matches either 'http' OR 'ftp'.

`\:` :: Matches the ':' character.

`\/` :: Matches the '/' character.

`([^/\r\n]+)` :: Matches any character and one or more matches that are not in the set. Meaning any character that is not '/', a return character or a new line.

`([^\r\n]*)` :: Matches any character and zero or more matches that are not in the set. See above.

Now the following is simply the last two parts of a URL. A URL is composed of `protocol://domain/path`

```
(?<domain>[^/\r\n]+)(?<path>/[^\r\n]*)?
```